# Where to ask about original version's name of a voiced-over documentary?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a documentary, originally in English but voiced-over in French.

I tried to find the original title but without any success.
Where would I ideally ask for such help?
If anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

I know there is `movies.stackexchange.com` but they do not state anything about documentaries (or identifying them, etc) in the tour page.

Comment: are documentaries not a subset of movies?

Comment: If it's a movie (and isn't a porno), you can ask about it on M&TV...

Answer (score 6):

Come on over to [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)!

We don't have any rules that the questions be about narrative projects. In fact, we have a few questions about [documentaries](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentary), [reality TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-tv) and other unscripted shows. The tour can't possibly list every acceptable topic, since there's so many, and if you have a question about whether the topic is OK, feel free to ask on our [Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: Yet we certainly *do* have rules about the quality of identification questions, though. Which isn't to say his question would automatically be a bad one, but the site has had bad experiences with "identify this YouTube clip" in the past.